# Using Geolocation in Manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on creating a Chrome Extension using Manifest v3.

I need to make a request to an API with the user's location, this currently happens asynchronously in the background using a service worker. However, the GeoLocation API is not available to service workers.

Any suggestions for how to incorporate user location without migrating to manifest v2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem lies in MV3 background service worker.
Calling geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error)
from background V2 does not generate any error, but triggers the error callback function
Basically it is as if the geolocation had not been successful.
You should call the localization methods (getCurentPosition or watchPosition) from an extension page.
Better if you call these methods following a "user gesture".
Bear in mind that some browsers do not fully support these APIs

Comment: It is a problem with the service worker.

The `geolocation` API is part of the `navigator` object. Service workers use a different navigator object which does not have access to `geolocation` which is why it triggers the error callback function. 

It would be unfortunate if using a "user gesture" was the best way of doing this, as the goal is to make the extension low touch.

Comment: I didn't say exactly that.
As you say at the moment there is no geoLocation inside navigator object.
From the tests I did before answering you, it would seem however that the 2 methods of the same object invoked by MV2 background scripts don't lead to great results.
I have tested with both Chrome and Canary.
Conversely, if you invoke these methods from an MV2 extension page, you have more luck.
Try making a small MV2 extension where you invoke one of the two geolocation methods from the background script.
If it works, please share your code as I haven't been able to do this yet.